# ошибка сервера javassist_123 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy при использовании hibernate.envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, envers

Приложение на spring4 использует jpa(с hibernate-provider'ом)  и запускается на websphere8.5.5.13

Нужно было поддержать историчность изменений сущностей и был добавлен hibernate-envers.
Таким образом можно запросить историю изменений сущности.

На сервере томкат - все ок
После перехода на север webshepere получаю ошибку 
javassist_123 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

мой pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <hb.enity.manager>4.2.21.Final</hb.enity.manager>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SERVLET-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

настройки hibernate:

```
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field", true);



properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
    properties.put("useSSL", false);
    properties.put("requireSSL", false);
    properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
    properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
    properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
    properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
    return properties;
}
```

Есть подозрения, что это связано с несовместимостью предоставляемых мною библиотек с теми, что используются на сервере.

**Попытки:**
Пробовал понизить версию hibernate-entity-manager и envers до 4.2.7.SP1, ошибка пропала, но это привело к тому, что в таблице истории во всех полях version null - значения.

Эта проблема проявляет себя при переходе от 4.2.7.SP1 к 4.2.8.Final
Список того, что поменялось есть [тут](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6004?jql=project%20%3D%20HHH%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20(4.2.8)%20ORDER%20BY%20updated)

Comment: Точно, это связано с несовместимость, но как это убрать, хотелось бы узнать, а также попытки.

Comment: @RomanC обновил вопрос